# Как сделать переключать checkbox используя JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можете подсказать как сделать такой checkbox используя js? Стилизовать не обязательно, просто хочу понять как такое сделать.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1389274/ - дубликат

Answer (score 3):

Тупо HTML и CSS

```css
.flip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid pink;
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 4px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 82px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.active:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 24px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .active:after {
  left: 104%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip">
  <input type="checkbox" id="flip">
  <label for="flip">
    <span class="active">No</span>
    <span>Yes</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Вот с JS

```js
const checkox = document.querySelectorAll('.checkox');

for (let i = 0; i < checkox.length; i++) {
  checkox[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.checkox {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 42px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 24px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.pereklyuchatel {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.active .pereklyuchatel,
.checkox.active:nth-child(2):after {
  left: calc(50% + 5px);
}

.checkox:nth-child(2):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkox">
  <div class="pereklyuchatel"></div>
</div>

<div class="checkox"></div>
```

Comment: Видел это решение. Интересует решение именно через JS, если такое возможно.

Comment: @rg234 поменял, можете посмотреть

Comment: Спасибо большое, не думал что решение через JS настолько простое

Comment: В варианте с JS чекбокс на сервер не улетит. Правда автор вопроса и не просил.

Comment: Laukhin Andrey, а возможно это как исправить? Или остается только html+css?

Comment: Лучше использовать вариант с HTML и CSS, это более эфективно и менее затратно по ресурсам

Comment: Да, конечно. В html добавить input, а в обработчик переключение. Автор ответа, если пожелает, внесёт изменения. Да и подходов к решению много.